# Java XML signature

Tags: java, xml, digital-signature

I try use Java digital signature API. I create *KeyPair* instance and all other XML signature elements and print output XML. My problem is with *KeyInfo* XML element.
In output XML looks like:

```
 <dsig:KeyInfo Id="KeyInfo001">
     <dsig:KeyValue>
      <dsig:RSAKeyValue>
 <dsig:Modulus>gFWMViozvknZVIfbuacK3pCWZpyFdOSMu2BkfUzjwD4xLwM1LCeWE8BgPVAFmsJHaob/5edRs+GU
uqNgKj106pEtNizMbqvYjiold3s1xHh0086dBPNbBh3/3b/DDeBXZ6kAuRwVaJeqOpsSeUZFBJ1q
gDZi4q7qoeMrOqAypDc=</dsig:Modulus>
       <dsig:Exponent>AQAB</dsig:Exponent>
     </dsig:RSAKeyValue>
    </dsig:KeyValue>
```

But if I want to print Modulus (public key) from *PublicKey* instance and create String from bytes, java doesn´t give me same result as in XML.

I can access to PublicKey like this:

```
keyPair.getPublicKey.getEncoded()
```

Please, some ideas?

Comment: You mean, you directly try to convert the bytes into a string? You should encode them with BASE64 instead. `Base64.getEncoder().encodeAsString(getMyModulusBytes())`

Comment: For better support, you should add what Java gives you as result.